# Dojo beginner question: How do I get my custom widget to render?

Tags: dojo

I am trying to write a simple Dojo HelloWorld Widget, but I cannot see the output in the browser.
The directory Structure:

```
tutorial
  dojotoolkit
      dijit
      dojo
      dojox
      my_ext
         HelloWorldWidget.js
  test.html
```

Below are the codes:

**HelloWorldWidget.js**

```
dojo.provide("my_ext.HelloWorldWidget");

dojo.require("dijit._Widget");
dojo.require("dijit._Templated");

dojo.declare(
"my_ext.HelloWorldWidget",[dijit._Widget,dijit._Templated], {
    templateString: '<div>This is a test</div>'
});
```

**test.html**

```
<html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var djConfig = {
        isDebug:true, parseOnLoad:true
        };
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="dojotoolkit/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("my_ext.HelloWorldWidget");
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
       <!-- as an HTML element with dojoType attribute -->
       <div dojoType="HelloWorldWidget"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It'll be really helpful if someone can point out the mistake. I have spent quite some time fruitlessly on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the console for error messages?

Your widget is called `my_ext.HelloWorldWidget`  dojoType needs that fully qualified name to find the widget.

Comment: well, I haven't put it on a server. I am just using it as static pages, so no console. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm referring to the Javascript console in the browser, which will work regardless of where your files are served, or even if they're run locally.  But besides finding the console, you might try changing the dojoType attribute value.

Comment: oh, ok. It says 'failed to load my_ext.HelloWorldWidget'. All the paths seem to be correct. Not sure whats happening.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, move this js block from head to body:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  dojo.require("my_ext.HelloWorldWidget");
</script>
```

The second use full name of your widget in dojoType attr:

```
<body>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("my_ext.HelloWorldWidget");
    </script>
    <div dojoType="my_ext.HelloWorldWidget"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Also, you don't need the `language="JavaScript"` on your tag anymore (and really, you don't even need the `type="text/javascript"` if you use the HTML5 doctype).